# Ubuntu Lenovo Y50 Intellij IDEA Crash

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, shutdown, lenovo, intellij

I have a very strange problem with IntelliJ or Ubuntu (or maybe with my laptop - Lenovo Y50).

Starting IntelliJ crashes the computer, but it happens only in certain situations, here are the examples:

1. **Power Supply plugged in.** IntelliJ starts just fine, loads project and everything is ok.
2. **Power Supply not plugged in.** IntelliJ starts, there is a welcome screen, I can choose project, and then, while loading the project the whole computer crashes, just a black screen and the laptop is off instantly.
3. **Power Supply plugged in only to start IntelliJ.** Here is the weirdest situation. When PS is plugged in, IDE starts and loads project normally. Then when I exit IntelliJ, unplug the power supply (so it is like #2 scenario) and try to start IntelliJ again, load any project - no problems at all.

So the crash happens while loading the project (no matter what type) and power is not plugged it. It looks just as the power from the battery is suddenly cut off. The problem was and is present in either Ubuntu 14.04 as well as 16.04.

I have also noticed that, even though when I am only on battery, sometimes it does not crash, but most times it does (about 90%)

I have looked all over the Internet and did not find any solution.
Here is [dmesg log](http://pastebin.com/bdRvJnWp) from after the crash.

Comment: I actually have the opposite behaviour. When the power supply is plugged in IntelliJ crashes and and I get a blank screen and reboot, or the system freezes up, needing to press bower button to reboot. If I unplug from the mains everything works fine. Looking at power management issues now http://askubuntu.com/questions/832629/laptop-shutdown-when-i-plug-charger