# Laptop shutdown when I plug charger

Tags: laptop, power-management, shutdown, crash, charging

I have Lenovo G50-45 and using Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS but from the last 4-5 days I am facing some issue while charging sometime.

When I plug the charging cord into laptop for system crash/shutdown without showing any error message.

I have contacted Lenovo team but they told me that there is issue with driver and we don't support Linux. You need to install windows then we will help you with windows driver, past I was using windows 10 pro and it was working fine.

I am not sure but I have notice that after updating ubuntu this issue started. Also it stop beep sound when I plug and unplug the charger.
If I plug the charger and start laptop then it work fine and charging is working fine. But if I plug charger while working sometime it shutdown.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I don't think there is a "driver" for charging functionality, I think that's handled by the BIOS. I could be wrong though.

Comment: What you suggest me to do?

Comment: I suggest you plug in the laptop first and then turn it on. Someone else posted yesterday or the day before his grandmother's laptop would beep every time it was plugged in or unplugged. You might to search his question here and see if anyone has answered him.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But my main concern is: my system shutdown when I plug charger sometime. Beep is not the issue. 

I have tried plug in the laptop first and then turn it on. It works fine but after re-plug sometime system crash. Seems like update or driver issue.

Comment: Also, help me with the dedicated _page or person or group_ who can help you me with **Ubuntu 16.04.01 issues**.  I have seen somewhere that this OS have 5 years of support. But unable to find the exact place for support.

Comment: Have you checked the manufacturer's web site for a BIOS update? If available, it will probably requires Windows to install it. Cheers, Al

Comment: @AmitRai 5 years of "support" means security patches and bug fixes. Ubuntu is FOSS; there is no "help desk".

Comment: Yes @heynnema, lenovo told me the same that install windows to update BIOS (might be possible BIOS making issue). But I have to remove ubuntu and reinstall windows. Is it possible, if I install windows in virtual machine and update BIOS?

Comment: @AmitRai - No, you can't do it from a VM, but you might try updating it from a live Windows PE environment. You might have to borrow a friend's Windows box to follow these instructions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825109.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I have removed Ubuntu and installed Windows 10 pro to update BIOS and contacted Lenovo customer care for the same they told me that your BIOS is already up-to-date with latest version. I have also tried all the instructions given by customer care for other troubleshooting, at last they told me everything is fine and we don't support Linux OS.

Comment: I am going to install Ubuntu again I think I have to live with this issue. :(

Comment: I think it's a good idea to leave Windows on, and reinstall Ubuntu for a dual-boot configuration. Never know when you'll need Windows again, eh? Let us know if you're still having problems after the reinstall, and we'll try more to get it fixed for you. Cheers, Al

Comment: Does your laptop have a removable battery? If so, try this. Remove the battery. Unplug the AC adapter. Hold down the power button for 10-15 seconds. Reinsert the battery and boot the computer. Now plug in your AC adapter and see if it still crashes. Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks @heynnema.bu
I don't like to work with windows environment... I am okay with Linux, so I have installed Ubuntu once again with Wine application.

Comment: Yes, I have removable battery. I have got the same instructions by Lenovo tech support. I tried hope it will work. My system is stable somehow... Will update you if I face the same issue. Cheers!